# Angular 2 two way data binding with ngModel

Tags: angular

First off I am new to Typescript and Angular 2 and this seems like an obvious answer but I can't seem to get it to work. I have the following model

```
export interface IBrand {
    brandID: number;
    name: string;
    image: string;
}
```

Then I have the component class

```
import { Component, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouteParams } from '@angular/router-deprecated'
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { IBrand } from './brand';
import { BrandService } from './brand.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'data-bind',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboardApp/brands/brand-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/dashboardApp/brands/brand-list.component.css']
})

export class BrandListComponent implements OnInit {
    brands: IBrand[];
    errorMessage: string;
    newBrand: IBrand;
    pageTitle: string = 'Brands';

    constructor(private _brandService: BrandService,
        private _router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._brandService.getBrands()
            .subscribe(
            brands => this.brands = brands,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }    
}
```

And then I have the following html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="brandName">Brand:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="brandName" [(ngModel)]="newBrand.name" />
</div>
```

I can't get the properties of IBrand to work successfully and I get the error

> platform-browser.umd.js:962 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

However I can bind it easily to something like pageTitle. Any ideas that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's been a while since I have asked this question, and it's starting to get some views so I will add my answer.

First I would need to change my interface to a class **and** add a constructor.

```
export class Brand {
  constructor() {}
  brandID: number;
  name: string;
  image: string;
}
```

Now that I have a constructor I can use the new operator to instantiate the object.

```
export class BrandListComponent implements OnInit {
  brands: Brand[];
  errorMessage: string;
  newBrand: Brand = new Brand();
  pageTitle: string = 'Brands';

  (...)
}
```

Now I have the desired brand initialized without any data and I can bind it to the model. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, I don't know why but when I follow angular docs https://angular.io/guide/forms#create-the-hero-model-class it has defined the fields inside constructor, and I get error of `cannot read property of undefined..` but when I follow your answer (moving fields outside contructor) I don't get any errror

Comment: That's because they are trying to create a class with values. In a lot of CRUD situations you want to be able to create an instance of the class with no values. If you added ? after each property name allowing them to be null or you could pass in a value. Then the angular docs version would work. Just depends on your needs.

Answer (score 6):

You could follow this approach if you don't want to use class.

```
export interface IBrand {
brandID: number;
name: string;
image: string;
}
```

And now you could create empty objects for typed variables like this.

```
brand: IBrand = {} as IBrand;
```

Avoid using classes if you just want to use it for type safety instead use interface as best practice to make your bundle size smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to initialize your `newBrand` property as described below:

```
export class BrandListComponent implements OnInit {
  brands: IBrand[];
  errorMessage: string;
  newBrand: IBrand = {}; // <-----
  pageTitle: string = 'Brands';

  (...)
}
```

In your case, this property is never initialized and you have the error:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Thanks! I get a typescript error now saying that "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IBrand'. Property 'brandID' is missing in type '{}'. Is that something I can ignore or do I need to instantiate the properties?

Answer (score 0):

You probably found out already, but you can/should use:
`newBrand: IBrand = {};`
if your interface properties are optional:

```
export interface IBrand {
    brandID?: number;
    name?: string;
    image?: string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to write a class for types. Not Interfaces.

```
newBrand: Brand = new Brand();
```