# Bind interface with html in angular 2 with typescript

Tags: typescript, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

Please Help me 
I want to bind an interface i.e

```
export interface IEmployee {
    code: string;
    name: string;
    gender: string;
}
```

with my Html i.e

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employees.code"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employees.name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employees.gender" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="Add" value="Add" (click)="onClick(employees)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

on button click I want to get input values from html to my class

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { IEmployee } from '../employee/employee';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';


@Component({
    selector:'my-home',
    templateUrl: 'app/home/home.component.html'

})

export class NewComponent
{
    employees: IEmployee;

    constructor(private _homeService: HomeService) {

    }

    onClick(employee: IEmployee) {
        this._homeService.Add(employee);
    }
}
```

but I am getting following error [click here!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxX05.jpg) for the error

Comment: Can u check the case sensitive try code instead of Code

Comment: Yeah I tried but still not working @Eldho

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44378038 might help

Comment: I think you should initialize the employee object; then only you can assign to a object. If i change to class instead of a interface and creating a new instance of employee it works.

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: `employee: IEmployee = {};` note the members of the interface should be declared as optional `:?`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad , your code did not work ,But  thanks for the reply

Comment: @Eldho thanks , your information worked for me.

Comment: Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

```
export class Employee implements IEmployee{
 code :string;
 name : string;

}
```

**Component**

```
export class NewComponent
{
  employee: Employee;

 constructor(private _homeService: HomeService) {
  employee = new Employee();
 }

//This interface will ensure basic information that IEmployee will be passed 
// to service
onClick(employee: IEmployee) {
    this._homeService.Add(employee);
  }
}
```